# NoClassDefFoundError: R$layout after installing SDK and ADT updates

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk, adt, noclassdeffounderror

I update SDK to 22.0.1 and did related ADT updates. After updates my successfully running code has broken down with following error in finding xml resource-

```
unable to resolve static field 1108 (layout_name) in pkgname/R$layout
.
.
.
some error log....
.
.
.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pkgname.R$layout
```

Please tell me what can be the reason of this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Right click on your project goto properties. Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. do the same for the library project also. Clean and Build.. try this

Comment: Hii Astha. Have you tried to config build path?

Comment: also check your import of R, if any other package's or android.R is imported than remove that !

Comment: and also chk you have add Android support version jar file.. :)

Comment: hellow...Have you solved your prob?

Comment: @ Raghunandan: Android Private Libraries is already selected.

Comment: @ Mit Bhatt: I tried adding Android support version jar  to build path, it didn't work :(

Comment: @ Tarsem: There is no other R.java imported than the file in which resource is present.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have updated the ADT, there might be the case that the references have been corrupted.

Try removing all external jars from the project(If any). You can add them back in after it's been cleaned.

Also check whether external libraries are placed in /libs folder or not.

Clean the project and check the build path. If it doesn't work, you must reStart your Eclipse and then check the project.properties file. It will help.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried removing all external jars, cleaning, then adding jars. It's not working. Please tell me how the project.properties file can help resolving this problem?

Comment: Hi Astha, Please try to recreate the project and copy all the files and resources in the concerned folders. If It works then It might be the issue due to updates. If not, then you must check for updates again. These kind of issues are common whenever a developer updates the plugins. Thanks!

Comment: I did this too. Didn't help.